# JQuery - if div does not have specific id anywhere among its descendants

Tags: jquery, if-statement

**if a div does not have any descedent div elements with a specific id, do something**

Am trying this without any success. My many attempts don't work.
Syntax seems ok, but I can't figure out the correct logic.
Note. the div with id [#my_selector] I am testing for is not an immediate child

```
    if ($('.fancybox-container div:not(:has[id="'+my_selector+'"])')) {
        // do this 
    }
```

and none of the below examples work either.
Can anyone please help figure this out?

```
    if ($(".fancybox-container").not('div:has[id="'+my_selector+'"]')) {}
    if ($(".fancybox-container").find('div:not(:has[id="'+my_selector+'"])')) {}
    if ($('.fancybox-container div:not(:has("#" + my_selector))')) {}
```

Comment: Use the selector that would FIND them and then test the .length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. ID must be unique so `if ($("#"+my_selector).length===0) ...`
2. If not ID then do the same with find `if ($(".fancybox-container").find(my_selector).length ===0) ...`

Comment: Solution 2 worked like a charm. A thousand thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `$('.fancybox-container #' + myselector)` and then check it's length. If the fancybox container does not contain any element of that ID it will return a length of zero:

```
if ($('.fancybox-container #' + myselector).length) {
  // Contains a descendent element with that ID
} else {
  // Does not contain a descendent element with that ID
}
```

Comment: Are you able to provide a full example or solution? Eg also showing how to check length

Comment: @Dan My bad, just clarified my answer to be more verbose.

Comment: I'm getting  
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .fancybox-container #[object HTMLDivElement]  
am using JQuery 3.3.1. Will test further